# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock' - Missing files

Tags: mysql, sockets, homebrew

I've just started with Homebrew and my msql was running. But I couldn't seem to log in. I've since restarted my computer and now it isn't running. I ran `ps -u mysql` to confirm this and it returned `UID   PID TTY           TIME CMD`

in my loaded php.ini file my socket command looks like this

```
; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
; http://php.net/mysql.default-socket
mysql.default_socket =
```

in my my.cnf file my socket is down as

```
# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
# basedir = .....
# datadir = .....  
# port = .....
# server_id = .....
# socket = .....
```

In my homebrew installation `\var\mysql\` I do not have a mysql.sock file.

So I guess my question is what do I need to fix this? Is it a case of creating a mysql.sock file (Which I don't know how to do) and then put filling in the blank or uncommented references to the socket in both the php.ini and my.cnf file?

There are a lot of questions around not being able to connect to MYSQL on S/O. Many of them are never answered. I have looked at a lot of them to try and fix the issue myself and failing that provide enough (hopefully relevant) information to far smarter people than me to try and fix it. Hopefully it is fixable and others will benefit from the question.

**Update**

I've updated my socket in both php.ini and my.cnf to be `/tmp/mysql.sock`. When I'm in my usr/local/var/mysql folder i can see that I have a PID file generated. If I run `mysqladmin version` I get `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/mysql/mysql.sock`

These are my logs:

```
150110 23:53:39 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/Jonnys-MacBook-Air.local.pid ended
150110 23:53:47 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2015-01-10 23:53:48 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-01-10 23:53:48 1660 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2015-01-10 23:53:48 1660 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-01-10 23:53:48 1660 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-01-10 23:53:48 1660 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-01-10 23:53:48 1660 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-01-10 23:53:48 1660 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-01-10 23:53:48 1660 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-01-10 23:53:48 1660 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-01-10 23:53:48 1660 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-01-10 23:53:48 1660 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-01-10 23:53:48 1660 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-01-10 23:53:48 1660 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-01-10 23:53:48 1660 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-01-10 23:53:48 1660 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.22 started; log sequence number 1637555
2015-01-10 23:53:48 1660 [Note] RSA private key file not found: /usr/local/var/mysql//private_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2015-01-10 23:53:48 1660 [Note] RSA public key file not found: /usr/local/var/mysql//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2015-01-10 23:53:48 1660 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2015-01-10 23:53:48 1660 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2015-01-10 23:53:48 1660 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2015-01-10 23:53:48 1660 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-01-10 23:53:48 1660 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.22/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.22'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Homebrew
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.22/bin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Binlog end
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2015-01-10 23:54:43 1660 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2015-01-10 23:54:44 1660 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1637565
2015-01-10 23:54:44 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2015-01-10 23:54:44 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2015-01-10 23:54:44 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2015-01-10 23:54:44 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2015-01-10 23:54:44 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2015-01-10 23:54:44 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2015-01-10 23:54:44 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2015-01-10 23:54:44 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2015-01-10 23:54:44 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2015-01-10 23:54:44 1660 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2015-01-10 23:54:44 1660 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.22/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

150110 23:55:16 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2015-01-10 23:55:17 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-01-10 23:55:17 462 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2015-01-10 23:55:17 462 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-01-10 23:55:17 462 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-01-10 23:55:17 462 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-01-10 23:55:17 462 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-01-10 23:55:17 462 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-01-10 23:55:17 462 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-01-10 23:55:17 462 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-01-10 23:55:17 462 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-01-10 23:55:17 462 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-01-10 23:55:17 462 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-01-10 23:55:17 462 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-01-10 23:55:17 462 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-01-10 23:55:17 462 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.22 started; log sequence number 1637565
2015-01-10 23:55:17 462 [Note] RSA private key file not found: /usr/local/var/mysql//private_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2015-01-10 23:55:17 462 [Note] RSA public key file not found: /usr/local/var/mysql//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2015-01-10 23:55:17 462 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2015-01-10 23:55:17 462 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2015-01-10 23:55:17 462 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2015-01-10 23:55:18 462 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-01-10 23:55:18 462 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.22/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.22'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Homebrew
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have this file ?

```
/tmp/mysql.sock
```

If so, try to add this in your php.ini

```
mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

and restart apache

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

else you have a problem and you should try to relaunch your mysqld service :

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

Comment: I don't seem to have that file. I don't have a tmp folder in my /usr/local/ folder

Comment: I ran `mysql_config --socket` and it came back with `/tmp/mysql.sock`. So  I updated my `php.ini` file. restarted Apache. I ran the last command and it said operation already in progress.